# Clouds: Amazon, Google, Microsoft - What kind of frameworks can I use?

Tags: java, cloud, jclouds

I need to develop some simple application like demo and this demo should connect to 3 clouds S3, Google Storage and Azure. This project is **java** based, Can I use some frameworks for it?
I've looked to the jclouds, native s3 and spring data and decided  to ask this question ...
Thanks

Comment: Is only the data stored in the cloud or also the application itself?

Comment: I'm not aware of any "hibernate like" framework for all those services, looks like Spring Data is your bet option since it supports S3 and Azure, although it doesn't look very mature yet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[JClouds](http://www.jclouds.org/) would seem top be a good choice here, providing a consistent API to interact with the various cloud services. Like any abstraction, it's probably not as functional as any of the "native" APIs, but it's under very active development, so it'll improve.

I suggest you pick one and try it.